# algorithm transfer one coin matrix to another coin matrix

Tags: c++

**Description:**
 There are m * n (m <= 100, n <=100) coins on the desktop forming a m row n column coin matrix. Every coin either face upward, or face backward, represented by 0 or 1.

Rules of the game are:

(1) every time, you are allowed to inverse one row of coins.
  (2) every time, you are allowed to swap two columns.

**Object:**
  from initial matrix -> target matrix

**Input:**
   1. k the count of test caese
   2. m n the count of rows and columns
   3. the numbers of the inital matrix and the target matrix

**Output**
   the least steps from initial matrix to target matrix, if it is not possible to transfer from initial to target, output -1.

**sample intput**

2
4 3
1 0 1
0 0 0
1 1 0
1 0 1

1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
1 0 1

4 3
1 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 1

1 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 1
1 0 1

**sample output**

2

-1

I have coded one solution: [mysolution.cc](https://code.google.com/p/wxd/source/browse/trunk/prog14.cc), which enumerate all posibilities and which is correct but it is too slow, could you provide a correct but fast solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows always stay in the same place, so if row `r` starts with `k` ones, it will always have either `k` ones or `columns - k`.

1. for each row, check if `count_of_ones(initial,row) == count_of_ones(target,row)`, if yes, fine, else check if `count_of_ones(initial,row) = columns - count_of_ones(target,row)`, if so, flip row, else output `-1`. As @maniek pointed out, it's not so easy when exactly half of the columns contain ones. Such rows would have to be treated in step 2 to try and form the required columns.
2. for each column, count the number of ones int the target and the working matrix (after flipping rows as appropriate). If the sequences of counts are not permutations of each other, output `-1`, otherwise try to find a permutation of columns that transforms working to target (any columns identical between working and target have to be kept fixed). If not possible, output `-1`, otherwise find minimum number of swaps necessary to achieve that permutation.

Comment: The second part is tricky. It is equivalent to: you have two arrays with numbers(not necessarily unique). Find the minimum number of swaps to convert the first array to the second array. What is the best algo you can think of?

Comment: First part is tricky too, when count_of_ones(initial,row) = count_of_ones(target,row) = columns/2 for all rows.

Comment: @maniek Good catch. In fact it already complicates matters if that holds for one row, considerably if it holds for several rows.

Comment: @Petar The minimal number of swaps to achieve a permutation of `n` elements with `o` orbits is `n-o`. So find a permutation (of the indices) that achieves the desired result and look at its orbits. Orbits containing identical numbers/columns can be split by transposing the corresponding indices. Thus you get a permutation achieving the desired result without splittable orbits. I think (no proof yet) the number of orbits under these conditions is unique. Will try to prove it after dinner.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some thoughts. You compare row by row. If the i-th row of the first matrix has the same number of 1 as in the i-th row of the second matrix - then you don't inverse. If the i-th row of the first matrix has the same number of 1 as the 0 in the i-th row of the second matrix - then you must inverse. If neither of this is true, then there is no solution. This is all about inversing.

Now all columns are equal but in a different order(the second matrix has permuted columns from the first matrix). If the columns are not permutation of each other - return -1. This problem is equal to find the minimum number of swaps to convert a one permutation to other.

Comment: Please note that if number of 0-s and 1-s in row is the same, you'll need to check both states - inverted, and not.